# BusinessWorks WriteFile not working

Tags: esb, tibco, businessworks

I'm new to BusinessWorks.  Here is the basic flow of my application:

[image]

1. ReceiveMail

   Basic configuration.  I'm positive this is working.
2. Flow (Link)

   Checks for an attachment

[image]

3. Log

   Outputs the attachment name like *Email has attachment: application/xml; name="test.xml"*

[image]

4. flow (link)

   Checks if it is the right attachment (currently "test.xml")

[image]

5. WriteFile

   Writes the file from $ReceiveMail/tns1:mimeEnvelopeElement/mimePart[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YYAx.png)/textContent

[image]

[image]

6. Log

   Output filename from $WriteFile/fileInfo/fullName

[image]

---

So, given all that, here is my output:

```
12:23:22.551 INFO: Started BW Application [EmailTest.application:1.0]
12:23:53.058 INFO: Email has attachment: application/xml; name="test.xml"
12:23:53.062 INFO: File written: C:\temp\out\test.xml
```

This tells me that the path checking for the "test.xml" attachment worked.  It also tells me that WriteFile is passing what I would expect as $WriteFile/fileInfo/fullName

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I was using WriteActivityInputTextClass in the WriteFile process, as you can see in the second WriteFile screenshot.  I changed "Write As" to binary on the first screenshot and then I had to remap the content and now it works.

I discovered this by arbitrarily attaching a couple HTML files to my email and removing the filename filter.  These worked fine.